# Postscript: how to convert a integer to string?

Tags: string, numbers, postscript

In postscript , the **cvs** **operator** is said to convert a number to a string. How should I use it ?
I tried :

```
100 100 moveto
3.14159 cvs show
```

or

```
100 100 moveto
3.14159 cvs string show
```

but it  didn't work.

Any help ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `3.14159 20 string cvs show`.

`string` needs a size and leaves the created string on the stack.  `cvs` needs a value and a string to store the converted value.

If you're doing lots of string conversions, it may be more efficient to create one string and reuse it in each conversion:

```
/s 20 string def
3.14159 s cvs show
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug in GhostScript (the language specification is unclear on that): It seems strings are not terminated by `cvs`, so if you have a `5 string` and convert first `-10.0` and then `0.0` the string holds `0.0.0` (GPL Ghostscript 9.26).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838019/postscript-does-cvs-terminate-the-string

Answer (score 13):

## tldr;

A common idiom is to use a literal string as a template.

```
 1.42857
(       ) cvs show
```

## more...

You can even do formatted output by presenting cvs with various substrings of a larger string.

```
%0123456.......
(2/7 =         ) dup 6 7 getinterval
2.85714 exch cvs pop show
```

But the [Ghostscript Style Guide](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps-style.htm) forbids this. And it's pretty much the only published Postscript Style Guide we have. ([A discussion about this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.postscript/browse_thread/thread/df8d74b067f660ba/) in comp.lang.postscript.) So a common recommendation is to allocate a fresh string when you need it and let the garbage collector earn its keep.

```
4.28571 7 string cvs show
```

Freshly allocating a string can be very important if you're wrapping this action in a procedure.

```
/toString { (          ) cvs } def
%    vs
/toString { 10 string cvs } def
```

If you allocate a fresh string, then the enclosing procedure can be treated as a *pure function* of its inputs. If you use an embedded literal string as the buffer, then this resulting string is *state-dependent* and will be invalidated if the generating procedure is run again.

## too much, don't do this...

As a last resort, the truly lazy hacker will hijack `=string`, the built-in 128-byte buffer used by `=` and `==` to output numbers (using, of course, our friend `cvs`). This is interpreter-specific and not portable according to the standard.

```
5.71428 =string cvs show
```

And if you like that one, you can combine it with `=`'s other trick: immediately evaluated names.

```
{ 7.14285 //=string cvs show }   % embed =string in this procedure
```

This shaves that extra microsecond off, and makes it much harder to interactively inspect the code. Calling `==` on this procedure will not reveal the fact that you are using `=string`; it looks just like any other string.

Using `=string` in this manner inherits all the *state-dependency* problems described in the last section, ramped up a notch because there's only one `=string` buffer. And it adds a portability issue to boot, since `=string` is non standard -- albeit available in historical Adobe implementations and Ghostscript -- it is a legacy hack and should be used only in situations where a legacy hack is appropriate.

---

## something else, no one (here) asked for...

One more trick for the bag, from [a post by Helge Blischke in comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/Is872XZ66FI/discussion). This is a simple way to get a zero-padded integer.

```
/bindec         % <integer> bindec <string_of_length_6>
{
        1000000 add 7 string cvs 1 6 getinterval
}bind def
```

Comment: 2 things: 1)  WHY is all that necessary? 2) Does a beginner need all those different hacks to make things a microsecond faster?

Comment: 1) You're right, it's probably not necessary. 2) No, again you're right, a beginner doesn't need any of these things. I should probably edit the answer and put a *tldr;* header around just the first code snippet. That's all you really need. The rest is just trying to give a deeper understanding and to reference things like the GS style guide and the existence of the comp.lang.postscript newsgroup.

Comment: @user242579 edited the answer. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Just to point out that the extra depth here is really useful sometimes - I was looking for right justifying a string with spaces and got the right idea here...