# PostScript: Does `cvs` terminate the string buffer?

Tags: string, data-conversion, postscript

One idea when using `cvs` is to help the garbage collector by re-using a string buffer, like

```
/s 5 string def
s 2 cvs %...
s 66 cvs %...
```

However when doing such a thing in a loop, the strings actually found in the buffer were:

```
(-40.0)
(-30.0)
(-20.0)
(-10.0)
(0.0.0)
(10.00)
(20.00)
(30.00)
(40.00)
```

So it seems the strings are not terminated when conversion ended (Found in GhostScript 9.26). Unfortunately the GhostScript reference manual is somewhat silent about whether the string will be terminated or not.

So the question is: *What is the expected behavior?*

When trying something like `val str dup 2 0 put cvs` the result was (as shown by `==`):

```
(-40.0)
(-30.0)
(-20.0)
(-10.0)
(0.0\0000)
(10.00)
(20.00)
(30.00)
(40.00)
```

So is re-using a string buffer a bad idea after all?

**Update 1:**

I found that the value put on the stack is correct, while the value in the buffer is not:

```
val s1 cvs pop            % leaves the wrong value in s1
val s1 cvs /s2 exch def   % leaves the correct value in s2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postscript strings are not C strings. In particular, they are not NUL-terminated; instead, they have explicit lengths, just like Postscript arrays. It is not possible to modify the length of a string (or array) once it is created, but it is possible to create a view ("interval" in Postscript terms) of a substring (or subarray). An interval is not a copy; it shares storage with the underlying string (array).

`cvs` takes a string (to be used as a buffer) as an argument, overwrites the initial segment of the buffer with the value argument converted to a string, and *returns that segment as an interval*. (See page 568 of the PLRM; I'm too lazy to retype it.) You'll want to use that return value if you don't want garbage at the end of your converted value. (But the returned value will only be valid as long as you don't use the underlying buffer for something else.)

Comment: Actually the information is spread: Page 38 (arrays): "*Additionally, there is an operator ( getinterval ) that creates a new array object whose value is a subinterval of an existing array; the old and new objects share the array elements in that subinterval.*", page 40 (strings): "*Copying a string object or creating a subinterval (substring) results in sharing the string’s value.*". I always had though the value returned is just the buffer for convenience (interpreting page 568: "*stores the text into string (...), and returns a string object designating the substring actually used.*").